# Correct statement of Fermat's Last Theorem

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I'm looking at the [wikipedia page on Fermat's Last Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem)

In the statement it requires $a,b,c$ to be *positive* integers.  Is that correct?  I always took it to be no solutions in non-zero integers.  But this wiki page makes a big deal out of the bases being positive.  Has some counter-example turned up using negative integers that I'm missing?  Otherwise, I think we should fix the wiki page.

Comment: $a^n+0^n=a^n$ for any $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $n\geq 3$.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy I think you misunderstood my question.  Did you miss the word "non-zero"?

Comment: If $n$ is even, then sign doesn't not matter. If $n$ is odd then put the negative number on the other side (eg $(-x)^n + y^n =(-z)^n \Leftrightarrow z^n + y^n =x^n$).

Comment: I didn't see that. I believe you are correct.

Comment: Because a solution in Z would yield one in N.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the multiple (basically equivalent) answers below.

Comment: Since the stronger statement (over $\mathbb Z$) is actually equivalent to the weaker (over $\mathbb N$), shouldn't the theorem always be stated over $\mathbb Z$?  Therefore I still think the wikipedia page should be modified.  Otherwise, why not just state it for prime exponents, since that's equivalent to the general case too?

Comment: @GregoryGrant: Because the version stated is the version that most people will identity as "Fermat's Last Theorem".

Comment: @GregoryGrant This really is just a matter of taste.  Clearly there's a balance between stating a theorem in the greatest generality (more obvious applications) and reducing it to its essential cases (capturing the "heart" of the theorem).  One school of thought would be that "all $n>2$" is more natural than "all primes $n$ except for $2$" and that "positive integer base" is more natural than "non-zero integer base".

Comment: I disagree, I think most mathematicians would identify it as over $\mathbb Z$.  The wiki page notwithstanding, none of my math textbooks state it that way, nor have I heard any mathematician use that restriction.

Comment: Wolfram's web pages state it over $\mathbb Z$.  Even Wolfram gets it right, I think the statement on the wiki page should be changed, given how trivially it is equivalent to the statement over $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I did a web search on "Fermat's Last Theorem" and every source on the first two pages of results states it over $\mathbb Z$ except wikipedia and Encyclopedia Britannica.  You guys are wrong.  I rest my case.

Comment: I modified the FLT wikipedia page to add a section on alternate equivalent statements.  It's equivalent over $\mathbb N$, $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Q$, as well as equivalent to $x^n+y^n=1$ over $\mathbb Q$.  Seemed like basic material that belongs on the page.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The formulations are equivalent. This is clear when $n$ is even (because then $x^n=(-x)^n$), so assume $n$ is odd. I will prove that if FLT has no positive solutions, it will have no non-zero solutions. We have few cases:

1. $a,b,c>0$ - we know this doesn't have solutions.
2. $a,b,c<0$ - if these were a solution, we would have $a^n+b^n=c^n$ and then by multiplying by $(-1)^n$ we would have $(-a)^n+(-b)^n=(-c)^n$ with $-a,-b,-c>0$.
3. $a,b<0, c>0$ - this is impossible, as then $a^n+b^n<0<c^n$
4. $a,b>0, c<0$ - same as above.
5. $a>0,b<0,c>0$ - if we have $a^n+b^n=c^n$, then $c^n+(-b)^n=a^n$.

Rest of the cases goes similarly, which I will leave for you.

Comment: Got it thank you, I accept this explanation.

Comment: Since the stronger statement (over $\mathbb Z$) is actually equivalent to the weaker (over $\mathbb N$), shouldn't the theorem always be stated over $\mathbb Z$?  Therefore I still think the wikipedia page should be modified.  Otherwise, why not just state it for prime exponents, since that's equivalent to the general case too?

Comment: @GregoryGrant I think the reasons it's usually stated over $\Bbb N$ are purely historical. This is how Fermat (iirc) has stated it, and so we keep it.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  My Latin is poor, but my reading of Fermat's note is that he simply refers to there being no "numbers" that satisfy the equation.  I don't think he specifies they must be positive.  The accepted translation is "It is impossible for a cube to be the sum of two cubes, a fourth power to be the sum of two fourth powers, or in general for any number that is a power greater than the second to be the sum of two like powers. I have discovered a truly marvelous demonstration of this proposition that this margin is too narrow to contain."

Answer (score 7):

We are considering the equation
$$
a^n + b^n = c^n.
$$
Clearly if $n$ is even, then negatives just go away, so let's say that $n$ is odd.

You have some cases. One case is where $a$ and $c$ are positive, but $b$ is negative. Then the equation is equivalent to $a^n = (-b)^n + c^n$. So this case isn't interesting. You also have the case where $a$ and $b$ are positive and $c$ is negative. But there clearly is not such solution. If all are negative we also don't get anything new.

Anyway, if you continue considering the different cases you will realize that the important case is where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are all positive.

As @quid says above, if you find a solution in the non-zero integers, then you will have a solution in the natural numbers.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose there is a solution in non-zero integers. If $n$ is even this immediately yields a soltution in positive integers.

So suppose $n$ is odd. If all three are negative, we clearly also get a positve solution. So assume one is negative two possitive (two negative, one positive can be reduced to this multipliying by $-1$). Clearly it cannot be $c$ that is negative, so assume it is $a$ but then we get  $ b^n =c^n  -a^n = c^n + (-a)^n$ a positive solution.

In brief, insisting on *positve* is irrelevant, there are no nono-zero solutions either.

Answer (score 4):

The person who had the best possible reason to think about the presentation of the conjecture is Andrew Wiles.  In his paper on Fermat's Last Theorem, the formulation is symmetrical and allows rational solutions:

> if $u^p + v^p + w^p = 0$ with $u,v,w$ rational and $p \geq 3$, then $uvw=0$.

It's interesting that he also chose to not use the traditional letters $x,y,z$ and $n$ for the variables in the problem.  His paper "buries the lede" by not giving the elementary form of FLT until the sixth page, and stays as far away as possible from the archetypal Diophantine form of FLT other than to mention he has proved it, and to quote Fermat's formulation in Latin below the dedication.

Comment: Thank you for this post.  I also looked up Wiles paper and indeed he does state it over $\mathbb Q$.  I have ten textbooks that state FLT.  Nine of them state it over $\mathbb Z$.  One of those actually claims Fermat originally stated it over $\mathbb N$ but that's not how I read Wiles quote.  I have one book that states it over $\mathbb N$, Scharlau and Opolka's "From Fermat to Minkowski".  Therefore I think the consensus in the math world is in contrast to the consensus on this page.

Comment: @GregoryGrant, FLT over rationals and FLT over integers are equivalent by clearing denominators. In modern number theory, equations over rational numbers are often way more tractable than equations over integers, which is probably why Wiles state that it's over $\mathbb{Q}$. (After all, he proved modularity of elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$, rather than $\mathbb{Z}$.)

Comment: @user31814 Very true.  In fact over $\mathbb Q$ you can go one step further and divide through both sides by $z^n$ to reduce it to a problem in two variables instead of three.  In other words FLT $\Leftrightarrow$ $x^n+y^n=1$ has no non-trivial solutions in $\mathbb Q$ for $n\geq3$.