# How to check whether $(x^n - 1)$ is an nth power?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, roots-of-unity

I am looking for a way to check whether $(x^n - 1)$ is an $nth$ power when $x$ is rational and $n\in \Bbb N$.

So far I found some solutions such as $(1.25^2 - 1)$ is $0.75^2$.

I also found I can write $(x^n - 1)$ as
$$(x - 1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+...+x+1)$$
or with roots of unity as
$$(x-1)(x-ζ_1)(x-ζ_2)...(x-ζ_{n-1}) \quad where \quad ζ_k = e^{2\pi ik/n}$$
Though the second method looked promising, I couldn't figure out any way through it. I have only basic knowledge in mathematics. I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Ever heard of Fermat's Last Theorem?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I also thought of Fermat's last theorem, however for odd $n$ we still have to deal with negative numbers.

Comment: @orlp By Fermat's Last Theorem $x^n+y^n=z^n$ has no integer solutions $x,y,z,n$ with $n\ge 3$, $xyz\neq 0$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280492/correct-statement-of-fermats-last-theorem

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, infact I reached a similar equation at one point. But somewhere read it's some 30 page proof and didn't go that way. Also I saw complex numbers are appearing among roots of unity when n > 2. Does this have anything to do with Fermat's n > 2?

Comment: @user236182 If I understood correctly, if $x^n-1=p^n$ (nth power), then $p^n+1=x^n$ will be impossible for n>2 as per FLT. I might be asking the internals of FLT proof, but do you know why this "n>2"? Does this have anything do with the complex numbers appearing among roots of unity when n>2?